# Selecting cells based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                     date,         myfield
exchange, symbol
CME,      ES         2015-10-20    345
          YM         2015-10-20    564
JSE,      SAB        2015-10-20    845
          CLS        2015-10-20    961
```

The combined fields of exchange+symbol form the index. I need to be able to select 'myfield' for a specific exchange+symbol on a specific date.

For example I need to be able to select my field for CME + YM + 2015-10-20 which is 564.

I am able to select my field as follows:

```
df.loc[('CME', 'YM'), 'myfield']
```

But I don't know how to select myfield for a specific date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
In [32]:
df.loc(axis=0)[df['myfield']==564,('CME','YM')]

Out[32]:
                   date  myfield
first second                    
CME   YM     2015-10-20      564
```

This specifies the axis first so that the [slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) performs what you want.